# Additional Drivers problem

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I have Lubuntu last version. When I open Software & Updates I select Additional Drivers and show me 3 things. I want to select `fglrx-updates` and press apply but after some seconds nothing happens and the first one is again selected.
What  can I do to select the 3 rd one?

Comment: It's probably failing for some reason. If you try manually installing the package from the terminal, you should be able to see what's wrong. What does `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` say?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended proprietary graphics driver for your computer is the best graphics driver to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait for a minute or two for the command to scan your computer's hardware. The results should identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your computer. Install the recommended proprietary graphics driver using `sudo apt-get install recommended-driver` where instead of `recommended-driver` substitute the package name of the recommended proprietary graphics driver. Reboot to enable the newly installed graphics driver.